# A proof of a property of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

Today during lecture my lecturer showed us this property, but provided no proof.

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {d_{n+1}\over d_n} >1$$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{n}=\infty $$

Is this property legit? (not to be disrespectful to my lecturer but he tends to make a lot of mistakes)

And if it is, what is the logic behind that property? How does it behave when the first limit tends to 1 or is less than 1?

Comment: What do you mean by the limit of $\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_{n}}$ when $x$ approaches $\infty$? Should it be $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's $$n\to\infty$$

Comment: Think about a sequence where the next number is about twice the previous one. Where does it go? What if every time the numbers are cut by 1/2?

Comment: $d_n = 1 - 1/n$ is a counterexample...

Comment: @AdamRubinson, You're right. I don't know what to make of it now.

Comment: No hold on, $d_{n+1} / d_n$ tends to 1 (which is not greater than 1) in my example. My bad.

Comment: Another interesting question is: if $d_{n+1}/d_n$ > 1 for all n and the limit doesn't exist, can $d_n$ be finite? I think the answer is no, but it is hard to prove

Comment: Actually this is not so hard to prove: $d_{n+1} / d_n$ does not converge to 1 means that there exists an epsilon > 0 such that $| 1 - d_{n+1} / d_n |$ > epsilon for an infinite subsequence of $n$, $n_k$ say. The "infinite" comes about because "finite" would mean that the sequence does converge to 1. Anyway, you can then write: $d_{n+1} / d_n$ > (1 + epsilon) and so using Thomas' method but with the subsequence we get the same result. Note that the $d_{n+1} / d_n$ which are not in the subsequence are all > 1 and so this completes the sketch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that this is a positive sequence. (You might have $\lim_{n\to \infty} d_n = -\infty$). There is a $M$ and $\delta > 0$ such that for $n\geq M$
$$
 d_{n+1}/d_n > 1 + \delta = a > 1.
$$
That is:
$$
d_{n+1} > ad_n.
$$
So for $n> M$: $$d_n > ad_{n-1} > a^2d_{n-2}... > a^{n-M}d_M.$$ Now let $n\to \infty$

Comment: Thanks, very nice reasoning. I might sound naive but how does one develop such familiarity with proving theorems/properties?

Comment: @TerryGoldenstein: I am sure that there are many theories out there about how people learn, but I think that it really all comes down to practice - practice - practice. That said, as with many things, it is good to try a lot on your own. Over time you start to see patterns showing up.

Answer (score 3):

Since we have $\lim_{n \to \infty } d_{n+1}/d_n > 1$,

Let us have $ \delta = \min \{ d_{n+1} - d_n: n\ge N \text{ for some N }\in \mathbb N\}$, then we have $ \lim_{n \to \infty} d_n > \lim_{n \to \infty} d_N + n\delta$ which diverges to $\infty $.

Comment: can you help me understand why $\lim_{n\to\infty} d_n > \lim_{n\to\infty} d_N + n\delta$?

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour since $\delta $ is the minimum of difference, we have $<$ and we know that $d_{n+1} = d_n + \delta $, but there are infinite terms ... so we have $n \delta $

Comment: that is helpful thx

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}>1$ then for there is a $\epsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies $\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}>1+\epsilon\implies e^{d_{n+1}-d_{n}}>e^{0+\epsilon^\prime}\implies |d_{n+1}-d_n|>\epsilon^\prime $. Then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|d_{n+1}-d_n|>\epsilon^\prime
$$
But this contradicts the criterion of convergence of sequences cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence converges $d_n\to L$, then eventually its terms must be almost all the same, so their ratios should approach $1$.  (I'm glossing over what happens if $L = 0,$ by the way -- this is just intuition.)

Answer (score 1):

Since the limit of ratios is greater than 1, eventually all terms have the same sign. If the sign is negative, then $d_n \to - \infty.$ For example consider $d_n=-(2^n)$, then $d_{n+1}/d_n=2,$ a constant, making the limit 2 as required, yet the terms approach $- \infty$ instead of $\infty$.

If the terms are eventually positive the conclusion follows, since if the limit is $a>1$ we can choose $c>1$ with also $c<a$ and eventually for $n \ge N$ we will have

[1] $d_N>0$

[2] $d_{N+k}>c^k\ d_N$

(where [2] is shown by induction). Then since $c^k \to \infty$ we have that $d_n$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hypotheses: 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{d_{n+1}}{d_n} > 1
$$
Now later assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d_n = L$.
We assume here that $L\ne 0$ and that $d_{n} \ne 0$, $\forall n \ge m$. 
Recall from (Limit Laws): 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{d_{n+1}}{d_n} = \dfrac{\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{n+1}} = \dfrac{L}{L} = 1
$$
which is a contradiction. 
If $L = 0$, repeat same argument with $b_n = a_n +1$.

Comment: This isn't enough to conclude the sequence diverges; monotonic increasing sequences converge as long as they are bounded. You need to show unboundedness.

Comment: You argument does not answer why the sequence could not converge to some limit.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=L$ where $L\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}=1$. (Can you see why?)

Thus if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}\ne1$ we know $(d_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverges.

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}>1$ then, for the most part $|d_{n+1}|>|d_n|$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=\pm\infty$.

Comment: If for all $n$ $d_n = 0$, then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}$?